# Is it possible to use arrayformula to copy the values above if the cell on its left is empty?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to populate a column (Cell C2) with the value of the cell in the column to its left (Cell B2) if B2 is not empty; if B2 is empty, then C2 equals to C1.

If B3 is not empty, then C3 equals to B3; if B3 is empty, C3 equals C2.

I try using an array formula, but it returns circular reference error. And I certainly can't use `INDEX` and `INDIRECT` either.

Please help.

The sample file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TXz5m5LtTF632bMrwIIDlO-4NMavgs6HA4FE8_BFhRs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste in **C3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D3:D<>"", IF(ROW(B3:B) <= MAX(IF(D3:D<>"", ROW(B3:B))),
 TEXT(VLOOKUP(ROW(B3:B), FILTER({ROW(B3:B), B3:B}, LEN(B3:B)), 2), 
 "dd mmm yyyy"), ), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Awesome. This actually solved the problem. Thank you very much . . . so much I'm yet to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vlookup on the row number:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(if(D3:D="","",vlookup(row(A3:A),if(B3:B<>"",{row(A3:A),B3:B}),2,true))))
```

[image]